# no such table: django_plotly_dash_statelessapp

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, render, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my app through Render app, and everything is good, except for the HTML link, it shows"no such table: django_plotly_dash_statelessapp". Not really sure how to solve that.

Also, does anyone know which app is free for deployment, I used to use Heroku, but they eliminate the free one from November.[no such table: django_plotly_dash_statelessapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHgFO.png)

Comment: run `py manage.py makemigrations && py manage.py migrate`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: Have you followed all the instruction mentioned here [django-plotly-dash](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash)? Also check this similar [error here](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/94)